# onfocus is not working javascript html; does not display calculate onfocus and on button click

Tags: javascript, html

It is my first time using the stackoverflow I have been a long time drifter here and finally got the courage to join in and get some help / critiques to enhance my coding skills.

I am currently stuck on this for two days and I can not seem to figure out what happened.

The way this code setup works is it validates text fields on blur, (which it does.)

On the first and second fieldset the user is asked to input:

- gross income
- check boxes male/female

If *male* `income tax = gross_income*0.19` else *female* `income tax = gross_income*0.17`.

Add that up to the percentage you get per dependencies after 2 dependencies.
Plus *cpp* and *ei* will give me the total deductions.(WIP)

The problem occurs as follows:

The value will add up for *cpp* and *ei* and show in alert but it will show `undefined` in the total dependencies.

In the second fieldset where I am calculating the total grace.

It would show as not a number in alert and place a value as `undefined` text box.

The total suppose to show up after clicking the button but it just blinks the total net income that says, `undefined`.

I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

EDIT: I would also appreciate if anyone can suggest me a better way to implement and validate check boxes.

```
/*convert gender dependencies income tax: based on the gender 

    -> Total Deductions
    if gender is male: 19% income tax will be deducted, if female: 17% will be deducted.
    CPP: is 6% of the total gross_income and EI: is 9% of the total gross_income Union Dues: 2% of the total gross_income
    -> Total Grace
    if number of dependencies are 3, 2% of total gross_income will be added, if 4, 4% of total gross_income will be added.
    Bonus: $150, and conveyance_allowance: $ 100.
    */


    var gross_income, 
        //gender = {genM: gross_income*0.19 , genF: gross_income*0.17}, 
        num_depend;
        //income_tax;

    var bonus, con_all;

    var CPP, EI;

    var tot_deduct, tot_grace, net_income;


    /*validating gross income*/



    function validate_gross(GROSS_INCOME)
    {
        this.GROSS_INCOME = gross_income;
        GROSS_INCOME = document.getElementById("GrossInput").value;
        //gross_income = parseFloat(gross_income);

         if(isNaN(GROSS_INCOME)) 
        {
            alert("ERROR: PLEASE ENTER A VALUE IN NUMBERS");
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").focus();
        }
        else if(GROSS_INCOME == null || GROSS_INCOME == "") 
        { 
            alert("ERROR: GROSS INCOME FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").focus();
        }
        else if(GROSS_INCOME <= "0")    
        { 
            alert("ERROR: GROSS INCOME MUST BE GREATER THAN ZERO"); 
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("GrossInput").focus();
        }

        else 
        {   
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return GROSS_INCOME = parseFloat(GROSS_INCOME);
        }
    }

    /*function validate gender()
    {
        //TO DO: enter your code here; Figure out how to validate the gender.
    }*/

    /*validate number of dependencies*/
    function validate_depend(NUM_DEPEND)
    {
        this.NUM_DEPEND = num_depend;
        NUM_DEPEND = document.getElementById("Depend").value;
        //gross_income = parseFloat(gross_income);

         if(isNaN(NUM_DEPEND) || NUM_DEPEND < "0") 
        {
            alert("ERROR: INVALID ENTRY");
            document.getElementById("Depend").value = "";
            document.getElementById("Depend").focus();
        }
        else if(NUM_DEPEND == null || NUM_DEPEND== "")  
        { 
            alert("ERROR: DEPENDANCE FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("Depend").value = "";
            document.getElementById("Depend").focus();
        }
        else if(NUM_DEPEND == "3")
        {   
            // alert("VALIDATED: gross_income * 0.02");

            return NUM_DEPEND = gross_income*0.02; parseFloat(NUM_DEPEND);
        }
        else if(NUM_DEPEND == "4")
        {
            // alert("VALIDATED: gross_income * 0.04");

            return NUM_DEPEND = gross_income*0.04; parseFloat(NUM_DEPEND);
        }
        else
        { 
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return NUM_DEPEND = parseFloat(NUM_DEPEND);
        }

    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*validate grace*/
    function validate_bonus(BONUS)
    {
        this.BONUS = bonus;

        BONUS = document.getElementById("Bonus").value;
        BONUS = parseFloat(BONUS);

        //validate bonus
        if(isNaN(BONUS))
        {
            alert("ERROR: NUMBER VALUES ONLY");
            document.getElementById("Bonus").value = "";
            document.getElementById("Bonus").focus();
        }
        else if(BONUS == null || BONUS == "")
        {
            alert("ERROR: BONUS FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("Bonus").value = "";
            document.getElementById("Bonus").focus();
        }
        else if(BONUS < 0)
        {
            alert("ERROR: BONUS CAN BE EITHER ZERO OR GREATER THAN ZERO");
            document.getElementById("Bonus").value = "";
            document.getElementById("Bonus").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return BONUS;parseFloat(BONUS);
        }
    }


    //validate con_all
    function validate_ca(CON_ALL)
    {
        this.CON_ALL = con_all;

        CON_ALL = document.getElementById("CA").value;
        CON_ALL = parseFloat(CON_ALL);

        if(isNaN(CON_ALL))
        {
            alert("ERROR: NUMBER VALUES ONLY");
            document.getElementById("CA").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CA").focus();
        }
        else if(CON_ALL == null || CON_ALL == "")
        {
            alert("ERROR: CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("CA").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CA").focus();
        }
        else if(CON_ALL < 0)
        {
            alert("ERROR: CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE CAN BE EITHER ZERO OR GREATER THAN ZERO");
            document.getElementById("CA").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CA").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return CON_ALL;parseFloat(CON_ALL);

        }
    }

    function tot_grace(TOT_GRACE)
    {   
        this.TOT_GRACE = tot_grace;
        TOT_GRACE = validate_depend(num_depend) + validate_bonus(bonus) + validate_ca(con_all);
        TOT_GRACE = parseFloat(TOT_GRACE);
        return alert(TOT_GRACE);

    }
    function display_grace()
    {
        document.getElementById("totGrace").value = tot_grace();    
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*deductions*/
    function validate_CPP(CPP)
    {
        this.CPP = CPP;

        CPP= document.getElementById("CPP").value;
        CPP = parseFloat(CPP);

        //validate deductions
        if(isNaN(CPP))
        {
            alert("ERROR: NUMBER VALUES ONLY");
            document.getElementById("CPP").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CPP").focus();
        }
        else if(CPP == null || CPP == "")
        {
            alert("ERROR: CPP FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("CPP").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CPP").focus();
        }
        else if(CPP < 0)
        {
            alert("ERROR: CPP CAN BE EITHER ZERO OR GREATER THAN ZERO");
            document.getElementById("CPP").value = "";
            document.getElementById("CPP").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return CPP;parseFloat(CPP);
        }
    }

    //validate con_all
    function validate_EI(EI)
    {
        this.EI = EI;

        EI = document.getElementById("EI").value;
        EI = parseFloat(EI);

        if(isNaN(EI))
        {
            alert("ERROR: NUMBER VALUES ONLY");
            document.getElementById("EI").value = "";
            document.getElementById("EI").focus();
        }
        else if(EI == null || EI == "")
        {
            alert("ERROR: CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE FIELD IS EMPTY");
            document.getElementById("EI").value = "";
            document.getElementById("EI").focus();
        }
        else if(EI < 0)
        {
            alert("ERROR: CONVEYANCE ALLOWANCE CAN BE EITHER ZERO OR GREATER THAN ZERO");
            document.getElementById("EI").value = "";
            document.getElementById("EI").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            // alert("VALIDATED");
            return EI;parseFloat(EI);

        }
    }

    function tot_deduct(TOT_DEDUCT)
    {   
        this.TOT_DEDUCT = tot_deduct;
        TOT_DEDUCT = validate_CPP(CPP) + validate_EI(EI);//add income tax as well.
        TOT_DEDUCT = parseFloat(TOT_DEDUCT);
        return alert(TOT_DEDUCT);

    }
    function display_deduct()
    {
        document.getElementById("totDeduct").value = tot_deduct();
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function display_net()
    {
        document.getElementById("totNet").value = net_income;
    }
    /*tot_deduct = income_tax + deduct.cpp + deduct.ei;
    net_income = gross_income - tot_deduct + tot_grace;*/
```

HTML that is used for this is as follows:

```
<html>
<head><title>Calculating Net Income</title></head>
<link href = "../css/net_income.css" type = "type/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
<body>
<!--Since it is only one HTML document:
    It has one flow, so HTML before Java script-->
<div id ="divstyle">
        <form><h1>NET INCOME</h1>
            <!--Fieldset1-->
            <fieldset>
                <legend>GROSS INCOME</legend>
                <label><b>Gross Income:</b><input type = "text" id = "GrossInput" onblur = "validate_gross(GrossInput)"></label>

                <label><b>Gender: Male:</b><input type = "checkbox" id = "Gender_Male"><b>Female:</b><input type = "checkbox" id = "Gender_Female"></label>

                <label><b>Dependencies:</b><input type = "text" id = "Depend" onblur = "validate_depend(Depend)"></label>       
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>GRACE</legend>
                <label><b>Grace:Bonus:</b><input type = "text" id = "Bonus" onblur = "validate_bonus(Bonus)"><b>CA:</b><input type = "text" id = "CA" onblur = "validate_ca(CA)"></label><br/>
                <label><b>total Grace:</b><input type = "text" id = "totGrace" onfocus = "display_grace()"></label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>DEDUCTIONS</legend>
                <label><b>Deductions:CPP:</b><input type = "text" id = "CPP" onblur = "validate_CPP(CPP)"><b>EI:</b><input type = "text" id = "EI" onblur = "validate_EI(EI)"></label><br/>
                <label><b>Total Deductions:</b><input type = "text" id = "totDeduct" onfocus = "display_deduct()"></label>
            </fieldset>
            <br/>

        <button id = "Calc_btn" onclick = "display_net(Calc_btn)">CALCULATE</button><br/><br/>
        <label><b>Net Income:</b><input type = "text" id = "totNet" ></label><br/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<!--<script type = "text/javascript" src ="../js/net_income.js"></script>-->
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="../js/OOP_Improved_Assignment7.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: When asking questions on SO you need to keep in mind that people answer those questions in their spare time. If your question is hard to read then the probability increases that the person willed to help is giving up. I already spend about 15 minutes trying to understand your problem, especially because the text was not easy to read without formatting. And I still don't really get what you are asking. I also looked at your code, but I don't see a place where the `gross_income*0.19` happens nor where the selected gender is checked.

Comment: Sorry;I am still working on it that's why it is still hard for me to make one understand what is going on. but even if I am not using gross_income*19 (which depends upon if you check the check box of male or female; gross_income*17 for male; gross_income*19 for female,) I would still get some value in the total grace total deduction total net. The only thing I am getting is for grace: NaN in alert, undefined in the text box. In deduct (sum of numbers) in alert, and undefined in the text box. Total net_income just blinks undefined when I click the calculate button.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `display_net()` function in your javascript to

```
/* HERE GOES YOUR OTHER CODES TO VALIDATE THE INPUT FIELD etc...*/    

function display_net() {
        var income_tax;
        var gross_income = parseInt(document.getElementById("GrossInput").value);
        var dependencies = parseInt(document.getElementById("Depend").value);
        if (dependencies > 2) {
            var depend = dependencies-2;
            var perc_per_depend = gross_income*0.02;
            var total_perc = depend*perc_per_depend;
        }
        var bonus = 150;        //As in your comment $150
        var ca = 100            //As in your comment $100
        if (document.getElementById('g1').checked) {
            income_tax = gross_income*0.19;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('g2').checked) {
            income_tax = gross_income*0.17;
        }
        var cpp = gross_income*0.06;
        var ei = gross_income*0.09;


        document.getElementById("Bonus").value = bonus;
        document.getElementById("CA").value = ca;

        var tot_grace = total_perc + bonus + ca;

        document.getElementById("totGrace").value = tot_grace;

        document.getElementById("CPP").value = cpp;
        document.getElementById("EI").value = ei;

        var tot_deduct = cpp + ei;

        document.getElementById("totDeduct").value = tot_deduct;

        document.getElementById("totNet").value = (gross_income + tot_grace) - tot_deduct;
    }
```

If I understood your question, this is what you need